# How can I comment a single line in XML?

Tags: xml, xml-comments

This rather is a verification just not to miss out.

Is/n't there a line-comment in XML? So, one without a closer, like "//" the compiler uses.

I saw *[How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml)* and several other discussions.

This type of comment would be practical to comment out a line without bothering its closer somewhere down.

Comment: XML is designed on the assumption that tools like editors will often perform word-wrapping, and that line endings are therefore fragile. It would be a bad idea if line endings had to be preserved just in case of comments.

Comment: Surely editors only wrap lines for *display*.  I've never known hard newlines to be added arbitrarily to the file itself.  

It's an infernal  nuisance not having a line comment.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

No, there is no way to comment a line in XML and have the comment end automatically on a linebreak.

XML has only [one definition for a comment](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments):

```
'<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

XML forbids `--` in comments to maintain [compatibility with SGML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842236/418413).

Comment: A workaround is to use line comments (`//`) and run a script to strip out those comments before use (can be part of a singe-step build process). It makes for a much more convenient way of using comments. (I have used this technique with [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) source (installer tool for Windows). A number of other steps were required for building the installer, so this was just one more step to add to a build script/process.)

Answer (score 21):

As others have said, there is no way to do a single line comment **legally** in XML that comments out multiple lines, *but*, there are ways to make commenting out segments of XML easier.

Looking at the example below, if you add '>' to line one, the XmlTag will be uncommented. Remove the '>' and it's commented out again. This is the simplest way that I've seen to quickly comment/uncomment XML without breaking things.

```
<!-- --
<XmlTag variable="0" />
<!-- -->
```

The added benefit is that you only manipulate the top comment, and the bottom comment can just sit there forever. This breaks compatibility with [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) and some XML parsers will barf on it. So long as this isn't a permanent fixture in your XML, and your parsers accept it, it's not really a problem.

Stack Overflow's and [Notepad++'s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) syntax highlighter treat it like a multi-line comment, C++'s [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) library treats it as a multi-line comment, and the only parser I've found so far that breaks is the one in .NET, specifically C#. So, be sure to first test that your tools, IDE, libraries, language, etc. accept it before using it.

If you care about SGML compatibility, simply use this instead:

```
<!-- -
<XmlTag variable="0" />
<!- -->
```

Add '->' to the top comment and a '-' to the bottom comment. The downside is having to edit the bottom comment each time, which would probably make it easier to just type in `<!--` at the top and `-->` at the bottom each time.

I also want to mention that other commenters recommend using an XML editor that allows you to right-click and comment/uncomment blocks of XML, which is probably preferable over fancy find/replace tricks (it would also make for a good answer in itself, but I've never used such tools. I just want to make sure the information isn't lost over time). I've personally never had to deal with XML enough to justify having an editor fancier than Notepad++, so this is totally up to you.

Comment: Good tip! would work just abt as useful if i sandwich every XmL line between a pair of comment tags. maybe a line comment wd be worked in a new version of XML.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is wrong. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments) says, *For compatibility, the string " -- " (double-hyphen) MUST NOT occur within comments.*

Comment: @kojiro If you don't care about compatibility with SGML, then it is perfectly legal.  I have yet to see any errors pop up by using this technique with various xml parsers.

Comment: Of course it's not legal. The spec is clear on that. XML parsers may follow Postel's Law and let you get away with it, but a compliant well-formedness checker will flag it.

Comment: As @kojiro says, a comment containing "--" is not well-formed XML. The phrase about "For compatibility" is merely the spec editors stating their reason for including this horrible rule: it does not mean you can ignore the rule if you aren't interested in compatibility. Downvoting the answer as it is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelKay  I'll leave the answer as is, because I still think it's valid.  Usually when I need to add/remove a line or a block of XML, it's merely for debugging purposes.  I'm not advocating putting this in production level code, but it remains a powerful debugging tool.

Comment: You could write it `<!-- ->` and have it be a matter of adding a dash instead of having non-XML.

Comment: @RyanWH carry on doing what works for you, but you seem to be depending on a bug in the XML parser you are using. Personally, I use an IDE (oXygen) that allows me to select a piece of XML text, right click, and ask to comment it out. Which seems a lot easier than your technique.

Answer (score 15):

It is the same as the HTML or JavaScript block comments:

```
<!-- The to-be-commented XML block goes here. -->
```

Answer (score 7):

Not orthodox, but it works for me sometimes; set your comment as another attribute:

```
<node usefulAttr="foo" comment="Your comment here..."/>
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments) only includes the block comments.