# Why am I getting this error Error accessing stax stream

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate.cfg.xml

[Error message: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588091/error-message-exception-in-thread-main-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-erro) This link did not help me solve my issue. I get the following error.What should I do?

```
 Jul 26, 2018 4:44:24 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
 INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.3.Final}
 Jul 26, 2018 4:44:24 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
 INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$2.run(ConfigLoader.java:62)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$2.run(ConfigLoader.java:53)
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:79)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
at com.internship.java.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:16)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
    ... 7 more
```

The following code is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!-- ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java ~ ~ License: 
  GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later. ~ See the 
  lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl- 
  2.1.html>. -->

    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate 
   Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
   "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >

   -<hibernate-configuration>


   -<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->


      <property 
     name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql94.Driver</property>

   <property 
   name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>

     <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>

   <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->


    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

      <!-- SQL dialect -->


      <property 
    name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

     <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->


    <property 


    name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider
   </property>

       <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->


      <property name="show_sql">true</property>

      <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->


         <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

      <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/hbm/Event.hbm.xml"/>
         <mapping class="com.test.java.UserDetails"/>

      </session-factory>

       </hibernate-configuration>
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you give your pom.xml file and tell us what is the server your run your application on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually get this error on project that have wrong XML parser in classpath.

Unfortunately, project are usually bloated by a lot of XML parser. Just clean them.

You can check

- xml-apis jar. Take only the version 2.7.1
- xerces / xercesImpl   the same: version 2.7.1
- Saxon / Saxon9 : If you use it with java8: you need to have a version 9.7 minimum

Comment: I added all the dependencies but still didn't solve the error

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/config/hibernate.cfg.xml])

Comment: Did you remove all other old parser ?  / What web-server did your application run on ?

Comment: In dependencies I also use this

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-agroal -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I also installed the jars and added them to the build path. If it helps